# Increse android app compatibility on google play store for new aps

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I recently(few weeks ago) published an app to Google Play(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kfm.Cugopol) and shared it with my friends. Unfortunately a lot of their devices aren't compatible with app version. I googled for a solution and found out that Google changed their policy that new apps can only be instaled on Android 8.0 and higher. Is there any way to make an app compatible with those devices.

On google play console I'm getting 3445/13000 devices which is not bad, but I would like to increase that number. I tried changing API level in player settings in Unity and changing android manifest to make it compatible with other screen sizes but there was no difference. Thanks in advance for all answers.

This is my manifest file. The commented sectioin acctualy decresed number of compatible devices when uncomented.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.kfm.Cugopol" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <!-- compatible-screens>
    <all small size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <all small size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <all small size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <all normal size screens
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
  </compatible-screens> !-->
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="227e5310-1392-471e-8e15-ce7701fd0b5e" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>¸
```

[Here are my player settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylm2L.png)

Comment: what's your minimum api level selected?

Comment: You can see it on the link. Minimum API is 4.1(16), and target API is highest installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable all three In *Target Architecture*  `ARMv7`, `ARM64`, `x86` for targeting almost all devices, you are losing a lot of users due to it.

Comment: I tried that as well but my build fails and shows this error: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: I managed to fix the error by instaling custom NDK (not using Unity the one that unity instals.) Now number of supported devices is 12k/13k which is what I was hoping for. Thank you for your help.